# SFX (Self-extracted) file extract without UI

Tags: c#, extract, archive, winrar, sfx

The problem is the next:
I get a SFX file what I want to extract, but I don't want to open it and select the installation path, I just want to install it to a defined path (add by argument or smth).

I use C# language and I've tried many ways to extract that file, but I can't find the solution.

I tried the followings:

- Rename the SFX .exe file to .rar and .zip, after that with System.Comparsion package, I tried to extract
- Run the SFX file with arguments (it works in silent mode, just I can't add custom path to it)
- Tried to extract the .exe file itself with RAR nuGet package (like NURar)

If you have any ideas please let me know.
Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: Why is the self-extracting RAR archive file not created with the options to install to a defined path without showing any window at all? WinRAR offers the appropriate SFX options on creating the SFX archive. It is even possible to add the comment file to the SFX archive with the appropriate SFX options to do the self-extraction completely silently. I recommend to start **WinRAR**, click in menu __Help__ on __Help topics__, expand on first tab __Contents__ the list item __Self-extracting modules__ and click on sublist item __GUI SFX modules: setup commands__. There is described all you need.

Comment: It's a little complicated because the SFX file is not made by myself, I just get it and I just want to atomate the extracting operation, but thanks for the answer.

Comment: The comment file with the SFX options (setup commands) can be added to the SFX archive with one WinRAR command line on SFX archive not being locked or fully encrypted. And last but not least an SFX RAR archive file is still a RAR archive file and can be extracted like all other RAR archive files using free [UnRAR.exe](https://www.rarlab.com/rar_add.htm) or a self-coded executable using free __UnRAR.dll__ or the open source __UnRAR__ source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least I used UnRAR.exe file with arguments to extract the SFX file.
Thanks to Mofi for the answer!

The process what I use for extract data if anyone need:

```
UnRAR.exe x -o+ "sfxpath" "extractpath"
```